# z-index drop down is not working?

Tags: html, css, z-index

The drop down z-index problem. the drop down is not showing on the front on the image.
here is the  [link for the site](http://hcapital.in/markup/)
the drop down with `Luke Carlose` Name.

Comment: where did you gave the z-index?? is it the dropdown menu ??

Comment: as i am not a core designer i have tried in drop down menu.

Comment: i think the dropdown is working an showing perfectly..!! what actually you need ??

Comment: @Sajad Lfc Now u can see the link above with the drop down menu is working fine. that i what i wanted. thanx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `overflow: hidden;` applied to the parent elements of the dropdown. Removing this from `.holder`, `.wrapper` and `#header` and it should respect the overflow once again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems your problem:

```
#header .holder {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change overflow to visible and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it - this is css chenges

**Add padding top in #nav**

```
 #nav{ padding-top: 66px; }
```

**Replace This css**

```
#header .holder {
    float: right; 
    overflow: visible;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 207px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change some css element i checked your site and replace this with old css

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5
{
padding:0px 0px;//chnage padding in this class
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown
{
position:relative;//change position from this class
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active:after
{
margin-top:-3px;//add new one in this class
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5:after
{
top:12%;//replace this
margin-top:8px;
}
```